# JS showing field if dropdown selected

Tags: php, javascript, html, magento

I am wanting to show a hidden field but only when an option is selected in the dropdown. It does not matter which option is selected but I need one to be selected.

Javascript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function Select(sel,id,nu){
document.getElementById(id).style.display=sel.selectedIndex==nu?'block':'none';
}
</script>
```

Selection:

```
    <select name="options[1]" id="select_1" 
class=" required-entry product-custom-option" 
title="" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice();displayCondition();Select(this,divShow,1)">
<option value="" >-- Please Select --</option>
<option value="1"  price="0" >Perfect </option>
<option value="2"  price="-35" >Excellent </option>
<option value="3"  price="-105" >Good </option>
<option value="4"  price="-140" >Poor </option>
<option value="5"  price="-252" >Broken </option>
</select>
```

The above onchange will only work if the first item is selected, so I am unsure how to make it work for any item selected. Also, I know the divShow should have some ' around it but I don't know how to write it into the following php:

```
    $extraParams .= ' onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice();displayCondition();Select(this,'."divShow".',1)"';
```

Div Box:

```
    <div id="divShow" style="display:none;">
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product) ?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do have to display simple quote to make `divShow` a JS string. In PHP (and in most of common languages) you escape them with `\`:

```
$extraParams .= ' onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice();displayCondition();Select(this,\'divShow\',1)"';
```

Without these quotes, your JS would try to look for `divShow` variable.

Comment: Thank you that solved half of my dilemma. Do you know what I need at the end after the divShow in the onChange? I tried period as a wildcard and that didn't help. And I tried putting 1,2,3,4,5 also to no avail. Thank you again

Comment: I don't really get what you need, but if you want divShow to be displayed for any other value than empty (`-- Please Select --`) you have to have the following condition satisfied: `sel.selectedIndex != 0 ? 'block' : 'none'`. So try to pass `0` and invert the condition.